# How to define two days' range relationship in TradingView Pine Script

Tags: syntax, pine-script

I am trying to code in pine script two days range relationship i.e. current session's trend with respect o its previous session's trend. The logic is simple - if close > previous high, write "Above Previous High", if close < previous low, write "Below Previous Low", and if close < previous high and close > previous low, write "Between Previous Day's Range". How can I code it with ternary operator in pine script?

I am failing to code the ternary operator, though it's logically correct, but there are some syntax error.

Comment: Show us your code so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below, I used the ternary operator to create the text and then used label to display it.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)
cond1 = close > high[1]
cond2 = close < low[1]
cond3 =  close < high[1] and close > low[1]

txt = cond1 ? 'Above Previous High' : cond2 ? 'Below Previous Low' : 'Between Previous Day\'s Range'

if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index,high,txt, textcolor = color.white)
```

Comment: I did the same too. I was missing the "". But then I realized it. Thanks a lot for your confirmation. There is another unsolved question of mine regarding ternary operator in Bull Bear Balance Indicator by Vadim Gimelfarb. I have already posted it. Can you please fix it? Regards.

Comment: if you post a link to the question I'll be more than happy to take a look